# How to fixed react select arrow icon to the top after selecting multiple items

Tags: css, reactjs, react-select

I am using React Select and everything is working, but the problem is that after multiple items are selected, the arrow icon position to the middle as the selected icon increases. How can I fix it to the top no matter how many selected items I select?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BafE.png

Comment: Whatever you had tried please add snip here to more clarity

Comment: @PramodKharade I tried to use dropdownIndicator and applied position but that does't work.

Comment: @PramodKharade you can check this screen shot attached.

Comment: Where is code which you have implemented. Add the code in question